# Identifying where a table begins in a Word doc

Tags: ms-access, import, ms-word, vba

I have a specific work doc that is produced daily which includes a paragraph of text followed by a table with a bunch of customer data. I need to import that data into an Access table.

I've found code, which I'll include below, which does just that. However it's not working as intended. Rather it's not working at all. I anticipate that it's because the word doc begins not with a table, but text.

So I have two options. 1) Find a way to format each document so it contains only the table (I'll have to automate this because we receive dozens of these files each day) or 2) adjust the code so that it detects *only* the table in the doc.

Is there a good way of doing either of these things?

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub cmdImport_Click()
Dim appWord As Word.Application, doc As Word.Document
Dim dbs As DAO.Database, rst As DAO.Recordset, strDoc As String

Set appWord = CreateObject("Word.Application") 'establish an instance of word
strDoc = CurrentProject.Path & "\cmoSheet.docx"  'set string to document path and file
Set doc = appWord.Documents.Open(strDoc) 'establish the document

Set dbs = CurrentDb 'establish the database to use (this is our current Database)
Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("cmoSheetTbl") 'establish the recordset

With doc.Tables(1) 'target table 1 in cmoSheet.docx

    For i = 2 To .Rows.Count 'cycle through rows in Tables(1) [we skip the first row because the table has headers]

        With rst
            .AddNew 'creating a new record
                ![ReviewerName] = doc.Tables(1).Cell(i, 1).Range.Text
                ![ProductDesc] = doc.Tables(1).Cell(i, 2).Range.Text
                ![NPI] = doc.Tables(1).Cell(i, 3).Range.Text
                ![LastName] = doc.Tables(1).Cell(i, 5).Range.Text
                ![FirstName] = doc.Tables(1).Cell(i, 6).Range.Text
                ![ProviderType] = doc.Tables(1).Cell(i, 7).Range.Text
                ![Specialty] = doc.Tables(1).Cell(i, 8).Range.Text
                ![BatchID] = doc.Tables(1).Cell(i, 9).Range.Text
                ![AdditionalDocs?] = doc.Tables(1).Cell(i, 10).Range.Text
            .Update 'update the whole record
        End With

    Next 'go to next row in Tables(1)

End With

rst.Close: Set rst = Nothing 'close and clear recordset
db.Close: Set rst = Nothing 'close and clear database
doc.Close: Set doc = Nothing 'close and clear document
appWord.Quit: Set appWord = Nothing 'close and clear MS Word

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nested `With` must be related to the outer `With`. In addition, adding `Option Explicit` will reveal a couple of errors in your code.

```
db.Close: Set rst = Nothing
```

should be:

```
dbs.Close: Set dbs= Nothing
```

Since you create an early binding to Word when declaring the variables, you can simply use the `New` keyword to create an instance:

```
Dim appWord As Word.Application, doc As Word.Document
Set appWord = New Word.Application
```

If you want to create a late bind to Word, remove the reference to it and declare the variable(s) as `Object`:

```
Dim appWord As Object, doc As Object
Set appWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
```

---

Try this:

```
Private Sub cmdImport_Click()

    Dim appWord As Word.Application, doc As Word.Document
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database, rst As DAO.Recordset, strDoc As String

    Set appWord = New Word.Application 'establish an instance of word
    strDoc = CurrentProject.Path & "\cmoSheet.docx"  'set string to document path and file
    Set doc = appWord.Documents.Open(strDoc) 'establish the document

    Set dbs = CurrentDb 'establish the database to use (this is our current Database)
    Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("cmoSheetTbl") 'establish the recordset

    With doc.Tables(1) 'target table 1 in cmoSheet.docx

        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 2 To .Rows.count 'cycle through rows in Tables(1) [we skip the first row because the table has headers]

            rst.AddNew 'creating a new record
            rst![ReviewerName] = .Cell(i, 1).Range.Text
            rst![ProductDesc] = .Cell(i, 2).Range.Text
            rst![NPI] = .Cell(i, 3).Range.Text
            rst![LastName] = .Cell(i, 5).Range.Text
            rst![FirstName] = .Cell(i, 6).Range.Text
            rst![ProviderType] = .Cell(i, 7).Range.Text
            rst![Specialty] = .Cell(i, 8).Range.Text
            rst![BatchID] = .Cell(i, 9).Range.Text
            rst![AdditionalDocs?] = .Cell(i, 10).Range.Text
            rst.Update 'update the whole record

        Next 'go to next row in Tables(1)
    End With

    rst.Close: Set rst = Nothing 'close and clear recordset
    dbs.Close: Set dbs = Nothing 'close and clear database
    doc.Close: Set doc = Nothing 'close and clear document
    appWord.Quit: Set appWord = Nothing 'close and clear MS Word

End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah I accidentally pasted the code I was running before I corrected a few of the errors like the db -> dbs. This actually runs fine now, even with the paragraph of text preceding and suffixing the table! Thank you! Now my only problem is the format. Every cell ends with a dot, looks almost like a bullet point. Is that word's table/cell delimeter? Can I remove it?

Comment: @Steven Not sure what bullet you mean. Are those being picked up by the `.Range.Text`? Can you post a sample of it?

Comment: I'm trying to post it unformatted here but it keeps being removed. The bullets are not included in the table's dataset, anywhere. I'll take a screen shot and post an [imgur link here](https://i.imgur.com/YHjELbm.jpg)

Comment: Hmm.. Try `Replace(.Cell(i, 1).Range.Text, Chr(149), vbNullString)`.

Comment: I tried `rst![ReviewerName] = Replace(doc.Tables(1).Cell(i, 1).Range.Text, Chr(149), vbNullString)` but, unfortunately, there was no change

Comment: Neither worked. I don't see an ASCII code anywhere for bullets. At least not one that chr() will recognize.

Comment: Okay, I did it! `MsgBox (Asc(""))` = 7 and that actually removed the bullet. Phew! My only issue now is that multiple instances of the Microsoft Word process cause the code to issue a prompt saying that I have the doc locked for editing. So I have to end the process prior to running the code. I guess I can do some sort of error handling?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148247/discussion-between-kostas-k-and-steven).